# Excel Formula outputting COUNTIF Value not the IF value

Tags: excel

I have a 'Simple' Formula but as the title describes I get the value of the `COUNTIF` not the `IF` :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,TRIM(LEFT(CONCATENATE("PS",SUBSTITUTE(D4," ","")),32))) = 0, TRIM(LEFT(CONCATENATE("PS",SUBSTITUTE(D4," ","")),32)), "Duplicate!!!!")
```

If no duplicate found it should output new value else state "Duplicate"

`Is it possible to see if this returned value exists in this column?`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: At least explain the downvote...

Comment: Not the down-voter but I cannot reproduce your behavior. Works as expected; returning *Yes* or *No* not the conditional numerical count of column C.

Comment: This cell should output yes/no in the column C if duplicates are found, I will revise the question...

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key. That formula CANNOT be put into column C because that would be a [Circular Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-fix-a-circular-reference-C17488E3-3CBE-4FA8-A6BC-1A6FFA64DB78). That is why you are getting a zero. A formula cannot reference the cell it is in and a circular reference cannot be resolved; hence it returns **0**.

Comment: Thankyou, however I have tried this in a different cell outside the working area and still get 0?

Comment: You have to remove the circular reference formulas from column C before you will get a valid return from the same formula in another cell. It is the same as if there was a `#VALUE!` error in column C; then every formula that referenced column C would return `#VALUE!` until the original error was fixed.